# Search implementation for Multilevel array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

i have JSON like below.

```
const testData = [
        {
            menu: 'Test',
            submenu: [
                {
                    menu: 'Test1',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            menu: 'Test1.1',


                        },
                        {
                            menu: 'Test1.2',


                        },
                        {
                            secondLevel: [
                                {
                                    menu: 'Test1.3',
                                    submenu: [
                                        {
                                            menu: 'Test1.4',

                                        },
                                        {
                                            menu: 'Test1.5',

                                        },

                                    ],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                },
```

i have used reduce function to traverse to search the expected word like Test1.1 i am getting proper value, whereas while search the Test1.4 is not coming up properly as it has secondLevel as parent object.
The code i used is below which is suggested in stackoverflow.

```
function search(data, value) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    const object = { ...e }
    const result = search(e.submenu || [], value)
    if (result.length) object.submenu = result
    if (e.menu == value || result.length) r.push(object)
    return r;
  }, [])
}
```

Please suggest best way to search the element in secondLevel object as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have the option to use a library, you might want to check out [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

Comment: I have modified you search method here: https://jsfiddle.net/srbh_ya16/nhzj0dq3/. If it solves your problem, I will add it as an answer.